# How does pendulous vane work?

Tags: aircraft-systems

The pendulous vane uses precession to correct a gyro by small jet air, but I   do not know how it works. As far as I study, when gyro is tiled, one of the doors open and the other one is closed. This principle seems to be hard for me to understand. Could you let me know the principle of pendulous vane, and how it corrects a gyro's error?

Comment: Nice diagram here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16376/how-are-attitude-indicators-kept-accurate/16417#16417

Comment: There's an excellent explanation of them [here](https://savageplane.wordpress.com/2017/06/06/gyroscope-basics-the-pendulous-vane-fallacy/#ampshare=https://savageplane.wordpress.com/2017/06/06/gyroscope-basics-the-pendulous-vane-fallacy/) if you can ignore the writer's delusional conspiracy ideas in the last paragraph