# Have you seen gyroscope horizon moving while flying long distances?

Tags: aircraft-design

I've seen video where a man is telling that pilots flying in aircrafts do not see gyroscope horizon drift while flying long distances.

I know this question might sound idiotic but I'm just curious if you have ever noticed actual gyroscope horizon (mechanical one) moving while flying long distances. If not, are those gyros compensated somehow?

Have you ever recorded that on your camera?

Comment: Ignore those idiotic videos.  If the Earth were flat, almost nothing in long distance air travel would work.

Comment: See also [this Q&A](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14657/15982). Particularly the part about corrections in ring laser gyros in [this answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/14659/15982)

Comment: @Simon Not to mention things like Earth orbit...